MuseScore 3 Cresc. Poco a Poco
So in my Musescore score, there is a part where I want to add cresc. poco a poco and I want it to sound like that not just a renamed cresc.. Is there a way for it to sound cresc. poco a poco in Musescore 3?

Are you familiar with the "dynamics method" hairpin property? While I don't automatically associate "poco a poco" with any particular volume curve, if you're just looking to change it up, that's the first setting I'd mess with. Yet another devastating loss in MS4.

Cresc. poco a poco vs. cresc. depends entirely at the rate that your crescendo increases in volume. You can (fairly obviously) force a cresc. poco a poco with a, say, 16-measure crescendo going from mezzo piano to mezzo forte.
So, at least to my knowledge, you're stuck with going for a long crescendo and/or one with not much difference between dynamics at each end. For example, a 32-measure long crescendo from pianissimo to fortissimo or a 6-measure crescendo from pianissimo to piano should both count as cresc. poco a poco.
If you want an uneven rate of crescendo, such as cresc. poco a poco for 6 measures and a steep cresc. for 2 measures, you'll similarly have to notate this yourself with the proper dynamics for endpoints (of crescendo markings). The dynamics can be invisible, but you still need to place them.

In MuseScore 3, you can write poco a poco cresc. then add a bunch of individual (invisible) dynamics and, using the Inspector, select each dynamic and set the Velocity, Velocity Change, and Change Speed properties as you want them.
In MuseScore 4, velocities are associated with individual notes, and the level of control seems to be more limited as of v. 4.4.

Is this compatible with cresc. lines and/or hairpins, or is this compatible with "cresc. poco a poco" as text only?

@Dekkadeci I haven't tried it. The only problem I can foresee is the possible conflict between MuseScore's handling of the lines/hairpins versus the invisible dynamics. But I would also think that by setting the hairpin velocity and velocity change to zero would resolve the conflict. That is, unless MuseScore playback prioritizes hairpins and lines over specific dynamic marks.

Again, I can only answer for Musescore 4.
What's the difference between a crescendo that goes from (say) p to f over 16 bars and one that does it 'poco a poco'?  None that I know of!
Write the cresc. line, with its dotted extension as usual.  Make sure the start and end dynamics are stated.   If you'd prefer to see the text 'cresc. poco a poco', hide the line, add the text.
Possibly a crescendo that goes from pp to ff over one bar might benefit from being labelled 'molto', one that takes 32 bars to make a more moderate change from being labelled 'poco a poco'.   But they will just be reminders - a 'Yes, I MEANT what I notated!'.  They shouldn't change anything!

would it sound the same as when a person plays that effect?

@PianoCat98: That's going to depend on the person! How are you expecting it to be played?

@PianoCat98 See my extended answer above.   But if you feel you'd play a 'poco a poco' crescendo any differently to a plain one, tell us how and we can discuss how to make playback emulate it.

its in the name a slow crescendo

@PianoCat98  OK.  But dig deeper into that idea.  p to f over 4 bars.   What's the difference between getting there 'poco a poco' and getting there 'regular'?

well it must be different other wise it would just say cresc. not cresc. poco a poco so they must not be the same thing!

@PianoCat98 'Poco a poco' warns the player that it's going to be a LONG crescendo.  Don't get there too soon!   But that merely confirms what a long hairpin or a long cresc. line already means.  It adds no new information.
